# How to delete large amount of nodes in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to delete 1 million nodes in cyphper at one query using web admin(i.e localhost:7474/browser).
These nodes is labeled as User. I ran following query, then returned Unknown error after waiting about 1minutes.

```
match (u:User) delete u
```

This query returned Unknown error every time. and I confirm my PC resources didn't lack.
I'm using Neo4j version 2.0.0 RC1 community edition. and Neo4j Hosted on local.
Is My trying way for deletion nodes wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do write operations with a reasonable transaction size of ~10-50k atomic operations. Therefore you can use `limit` and run the statement until all users are gone:

```
match (u:User) with u limit 1000 delete u
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried to delete above query, but it returned an Unknown error. I executed an following query instead.
`match (u:User) with u limit 1000 delete u` 
It works fine:)
Thanx

Answer (score 4):

With Neo4j 3.x and forward you can run large delete transactions using [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate) too:

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate("MATCH (u:User) return u", "DETACH DELETE u", {batchSize:1000})
yield batches, total return batches, total
```

Answer (score -3):

I've found that just removing the `neo4j/data` folder is the fastest way to delete the db.